# Opencart VqMod permissions issues

Tags: permissions, opencart

I have recently copied an opencart install to create a development environment.  The issue I am having is that the vqmod files are getting "locked".  I dont have permissions to update them in the new dev environment and if I delete them on the ftp server, they somehow re appear the next time after I have loaded that page.  Any help would be awesome. THis is driving me crazy and preventing me from making necessary changes! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vQmod Cache files are generated with each page load as they are needed. Make sure you are using the latest version (currently 2.3.0). If you can't delete the folder for them, you should be able to rename the folder and then create a new one which you can access and your server should be able to write to it. If that's not possible back up your xml files in `/vqmod/xml/`, then delete vQmod entirely, and upload a fresh copy, then copy all of your xml files into `/vqmod/xml/`

Comment: thanks Jay, I eventually figured the same thing out. I appreciate your response.